# How do I use output of indexes to subset my dataframe?

Tags: r

I want to match vector 1 to vector 2 to see if items in vector 1 and found in vector 2. Then I want to create 2 new vectors - a subset of vector 1 of the rows of values contained both vectors, and a subset of vector 1 for the values not found in both vectors. `match()` function followed by `which(is.na())` works great for small data sets, but I have a data set with 1000 elements.

```
Data1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
Data2 <- c(1, 3, 5, 6, 7) 

#Match vector1 to vector2  
A <- match(Data1, Data2) 
[1]  1 NA  2 NA  3

#to obtain positions of non matching elements
x <- which(is.na(A), arr.ind = TRUE)
[1] 2 4

Data1[c(2,4)]

#to obtain positions of matching elements
y < which(A >= 1) 
[1] 1 3 5

Data1[c(1,3,5)]
```

Comment: `split(Data2, !is.na(match(Data2, Data1)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this so you do not have to deal with the NAs from match():

```r
Data1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
Data2 <- c(1, 3, 5, 6, 7)

# Values of Data1 in Data2
A <- Data1[Data1 %in% Data2]
A

# output:
# > A
# [1] 1 3 5

# create not in function
'%ni%' <- Negate('%in%')

# Values of Data1 not in Data2
B <- Data1[Data1 %ni% Data2]
B

# output:
# > B
# [1] 2 4
```